# Internationalization of placeholders in Spring

Tags: spring, internationalization, jsp-tags

I can not find the way to internationalize the text inside a placeholder like I do with regular text. I would like to place my internationalization in:

input type="text" class="form-control" name="s" placeHolder="Search Hobbies"

with **input type="text" class="form-control" name="s" placeHolder="ctrlpanel.search.placeholder"**

ctrlpanel.search.placeholder=Search Hobbies

Right now, in my JSP I include the tag

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<c:set var="contextRoot" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />   
<c:url var="search" value="/search" />


<hr/>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <form action="${search}" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
    value="${_csrf.token}" />
   <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="s" placeHolder="Search Hobbies">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
     <button id="search-button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
     <spring:message code="ctrlpanel.find.button" text="default text" />
     </button>
    </span>   
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

My configuration works fine:

```
package com.caveofprogramming.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver;

import java.util.Locale;


@Configuration
public class SpringMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){
        SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        sessionLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("es", "ES"));
        //sessionLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return sessionLocaleResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor(){
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return localeChangeInterceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry interceptorRegistry){
        interceptorRegistry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Since this does not work.

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="s" placeHolder="<spring:message code="ctrlpanel.search.placeholder"/>">
```

Comment: What makes you think you can't do it exactly like you're doing for "regular text"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use var attribute of spring:message which is used when binding the result to the page, request, session or application scope.

```
<spring:message code="ctrlpanel.search.placeholder" var="searchPlaceholder"/>
```

And then update your input field like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="s" placeHolder="${searchPlaceholder}">
```